# SQL Update Query on this Unusual Records

Tags: sql

I need a few pointer on solving this

For example `tblStudent`

```
ID      SNUM   Name    Grade
1       ST01
2       ST02
3       ST03
4       ST04
5              Simon
6              Kim    
7              Jessica
8              Dale
9                       12
10                      11
11                      11
12                      10
```

And so on... The pattern is pretty obvious... I need either an update query of its own table or an insert query to a new table that look something like

```
ID      SNUM   Name    Grade
1       ST01   Simon   12
2       ST02   Kim     11
3       ST03   Jessica 11
4       ST04   Dale    10
```

Can anyone point me a direction as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using MySQL , sql server or something else ?

Comment: SQL Server which version?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to obtain the desired resultset, try

```
    select t1.id
         , t1.SNUM
         , t2.name
         , t3.grade
      from (
                select count(*) cnt
                  from tblStudent tagg
                 where tagg.SNUM is not null
           ) agg
cross join tblStudent   t1
      join tblStudent   t2  on ( t2.id = t1.id + agg.cnt )
      join tblStudent   t3  on ( t3.id = t2.id + agg.cnt )
     where t1.SNUM   IS NOT NULL
       and t2.name   IS NOT NULL
       and t3.grade  IS NOT NULL
         ;
```

explanation:
basically, the sql first counts the number of target records and splits the original table into the obvious 3 parts. these are joined and from each one of them, partial information is extracted to build complete record.

**This scheme assumes that data at a given offset in each of the tables involved belong to the same entity**

given this assumption, the join condition may refer to the number of target records as an offset.

more tests can be added if required (eg. the parts in `tblStudent` have the same sizes, exactly 1 column in each section is not null, no column contains non-null values in more than 1 section).

tested on oracle 12 (should work on all sql engines though).

Comment: Umm, thanks for your answer, can you explain a bit because in sqlfiddle I got an error Unknown column 'agg.cnt' in 'on clause': select t1.ID , t1.SNUM , t2.NAME , t3.GRADE from table_name t1 join table_name t2 on ( t2.ID = t1.ID + agg.cnt ) join table_name t3 on ( t3.ID = t2.ID + agg.cnt ) cross join ( select count(*) cnt from table_name tagg where tagg.SNUM is not null ) agg where t1.SNUM IS NOT NULL and t2.NAME IS NOT NULL and t3.GRADE IS NOT NULL

Comment: I corrected the order of the base tables in the statement which caused the syntax error. i apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: No need to apologize, I should be thanking you for helping me :) in sqlfiddle, your select statement seems not getting any result can you take a look, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ffa5/3

Comment: empty strings are not `null` values ! after adjustment of your insert statements. the query produces the expected result ([try this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a84bf/1))

Comment: @user1618180: your fiddle is set to run in MySQL.

Comment: @KarlKieninger thanks for the hint - applied to my fiddle too, though the code works for sql server 2008, too (fiddle setting adjusted).

Comment: Genius Collapsar!! I guess I need to learn cross join... By any chance is there another way that you can think of?

Comment: thanks for the kudos :). unfortunately i can't think of another way in portable sql (which does by no means rule out the existence). however, most market leader rdbms have proprietary extensions which might address this issue.

Comment: I actually need the code to put into a stored procedure, combine with a web service to clean up the table. Thus I cant use other extension manually clean up the table. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you were 2012 you could do:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID
        ,SNUM
        ,LEAD(Name,a.ct,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ID) Name
        ,LEAD(Grade,a.ct * 2,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ID) Grade
    FROM Student
         CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT COUNT(1) ct FROM Student WHERE Name IS NOT NULL) a
) 
SELECT * 
  FROM cte 
 WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Just saw you comment that you are in 2008. I'll mention 2014 Express is now available. You are on a free version that is 8 years old. Consider coming up to at least 2012 Express asap.

Comment: I learned .net back when VS2010 just came out thus I am still old school ><